# Des / Les images surgissent de nulle part

Tags: articles

> Je ne veux pas m’approcher du champ. **Des** images surgissent de nulle
> part. Les corps, le sang.

Le contexte : A. doit traverser le champ devant une église où il fera une halte, mais ce lieu est dangereux et, involontairement, les images de la bataille précédente surgissent dans sa mémoire.

Est-il possible d'employer l'article défini devant *images* pour souligner que celles-ci sont très vives et troublantes ?

Answer (score 2):

Tu peux mais il faut définir ces images :

> Je ne veux pas m’approcher du champ. Les images de la bataille précédente surgissent dans mon esprit.

Je ne pense cependant pas que ça influe sur la vivacité de ces images.

Comment: Non, je ne veux pas reformuler, le rythme serait rompu. Si je laisse les phrases telles quelles, est-il quand même possible de mettre un article défini devant _images_ ?

Comment: Pour moi, *des* s'impose s'il faut garder le reste de la phrase.

Comment: OK, merci. Mais est-ce que l'article défini devant _corps_ et _sang_ est correct ?

Comment: *Les corps* est possible car ils sont identifiés, ce sont les corps des victimes de la bataille. *Le sang* est aussi possible, c'est le sang qui a coulé ce jour là. Tu aurais bien sûr aussi pu écrire *Des corps, du sang*.

Comment: D'accord, merci.